# How can I create irregularly shaped networks in Tensorflow and Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm making a neural network with tensorflow 2 and keras, but unlike all the tutorials I have found, my net is sort of irregularly shaped:

[image]

It consists of an input layer, 7 hidden layers, and one output layer. However, the input and first 4 hidden layers are split into two, and then later the two parts converge in the 5th hidden layer and from then on the network functions as normal. It is built this way because the network is meant to compare two positions and predict which is better. If you're interested in the concept, it's based on [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09667.pdf) research paper.

I do not know how to make a network shaped this in keras and tensorflow, but here is my attempt:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_train, z_train, y_train = list(int(i) for i in "100000000000010000000000001000000000000100000000000010000000001000000"
                                                 "000010000000000100000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000001"
                                                 "000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000"
                                                 "001000000000000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000100000000000"
                                                 "010000000000001000000000000100000000000010000000001000000000010000000"
                                                 "00010000001111000000000000000000000000"), \
                            list(int(i) for i in "100000000000010000000000001000000000000100000000000010000000001000000"
                                                 "000010000000000100000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000001"
                                                 "000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000"
                                                 "001000000000000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000100000000000"
                                                 "010000000000001000000000000100000000000010000000001000000000010000000"
                                                 "00010000001111000000000000000000000000"), [0, 1]

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset

network_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1594,))
model_a = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output1 = model_a(network_input[:797])

model_b = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output2 = model_b(network_input[797:])

x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([output1, output2])
model_c = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output = model_c(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(network_input, output)

# compile the models
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# run the models
x_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train)
z_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(z_train)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train)

p = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x_train, z_train]), y_train

model.fit(p)
```

which gives the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 "/Users/max/Desktop/ArmstrongChess/error recreation.py"
2020-11-02 21:29:53.387241: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-11-02 21:29:53.450960: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7ff74fd79dd0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-11-02 21:29:53.450979: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/max/Desktop/ArmstrongChess/error recreation.py", line 65, in <module>
    model.fit(p)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1049, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1105, in __init__
    self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 282, in __init__
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1594, 2
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

basically, I am trying to create it as three networks, the first two of which feed into the last to replicate the diagram above.

Can anyone explain how to do this? I'm a bit stuck.

---

---

Here is the code I tried according to tushv89's answer. I added some comments to let you know about the situation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# in my actual project I have a function that creates this training data from a textfile of game PGNs, so what I call is this: "x_train, z_train, y_train = randomize_data(["won", "drawn", "lost"])". The following is just the information for one game so I don't have to paste a massive function here.

x_train, z_train, y_train = list(int(i) for i in "100000000000010000000000001000000000000100000000000010000000001000000"
                                                 "000010000000000100000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000001"
                                                 "000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000"
                                                 "001000000000000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000100000000000"
                                                 "010000000000001000000000000100000000000010000000001000000000010000000"
                                                 "00010000001111000000000000000000000000"), \
                            list(int(i) for i in "100000000000010000000000001000000000000100000000000010000000001000000"
                                                 "000010000000000100000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000001"
                                                 "000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
                                                 "000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000000"
                                                 "001000000000000000000000001000000000001000000000001000000100000000000"
                                                 "010000000000001000000000000100000000000010000000001000000000010000000"
                                                 "00010000001111000000000000000000000000"), [0, 1]

# your code, copy pasted from here to the next comment
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1594,))

inp1, inp2 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.split(x, 2, axis=1))(input)

model_a = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output1 = model_a(input)

model_b = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output2 = model_b(input)

x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([output1, output2])
model_c = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output = model_c(x)

# your code ends here. 
# I create the model with the input and output variables from your code
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
# I compile the model with my preferred settings (although I have no idea which would be the optimised settings, all I know is that I want sigmoid so the predictions are between 0 and 1)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# I convert the training variables to tensors
x_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train)
z_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(z_train)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train)

# I call the network
model.fit(tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x_train, z_train]), y_train)
```

error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/max/Desktop/ArmstrongChess/error recreation.py", line 61, in <module>
    model.fit(tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x_train, z_train]), y_train)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1049, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1105, in __init__
    self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 282, in __init__
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1594
  y sizes: 2
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using standard slicing, use `tf.split`. It's much cleaner.

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1594,))

inp1, inp2 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.split(x, 2, axis=1))(input)

model_a = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output1 = model_a(input)

model_b = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output2 = model_b(input)

x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([output1, output2])
model_c = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="sigmoid"),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output = model_c(x)
```

Comment: When I tried that, it gave the following error: `ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<built-in function input>) with an unsupported type (<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>) to a Tensor.` Is that a problem with my input then?

Comment: @Maxijazz Interesting! Can you tell me the exact input, tf version as well as any changes you did to this (even if minor)?

Comment: @tushv89 tf 2, and I added the full code with little comments telling you what was your code and what I added and why. The error also changed, It turns out I was just calling convert_to_tensor on the wrong thing. Now the new error (the full error code of which is shown in the updated question) is `ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1594
  y sizes: 2
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.`